SPNEGO and GSS-API features inside eclipse-temurin jre image
As a requirement, inside our current java 17 jre image we need to include curl and kerberos utilities for debugging purposes, the issue comes when the curl and libcurl packages don't incorporate the --negotiate flag for SPNEGO nor the gss-api functions, our dockerfile looks like this currently:
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine RUN apk add --no-cache curl bind-tools krb5-libs krb5 krb5-dev bash openldap openldap-back-mdb openldap-clients

Could you please let me know if it's an Alpine related problem/issue to be directly addressed with them? I started thinking the curl/libcurl package they have doesn't incorporate these features.
Thank you in advance for your time helping me out.
I tried finding previous situations such as mine, looking different forums' advice and building the image locally to find out the kerberos tooling wasn't there:
curl 8.10.1 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/8.10.1 OpenSSL/3.3.2 zlib/1.3.1 brotli/1.1.0 zstd/1.5.6 c-ares/1.33.1 libidn2/2.3.7 libpsl/0.21.5 nghttp2/1.62.1 Release-Date: 2024-09-18 Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ipfs ipns mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp ws wss Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM PSL SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd


op here. After hours trying different curl built in versions, a work colleague came with the idea of manually installing the curl version of our choice (I knew from personal installation that 8.4.0 had both GSS-API and SPNEGO features enabled) inside the container this way:
RUN wget https://curl.se/download/curl-8.4.0.tar.gz && \
tar -xzf curl-8.4.0.tar.gz && \
cd curl-8.4.0 && \
./configure --with-gssapi --with-ssl && \
make && make install

Note: needed dependencies were installed too so that could work, making the image slightly heavier than it should for what's required, please reach out in case you need troubleshooting with something similar, as not having every dependency will trigger a failure during the make install and configuration steps
